# How to create a cartesian product excluding some results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, cartesian-product

For my calculations, I need all 32-element cartesian products composed of 0 and 1, where there is twelve 1.

I'm currently using the following method:

```
for k,l in enumerate(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=32)):
        if l.count(1)==12:                                        
            # rest code
```

But as you can see, it is not very optimal for such a large cartesian product.

How build the list that I need without having to go through all the elements `itertools.product` and without an additional `if` condition? Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only generate lists of `bits` elements where `ones` are `1` and the rest are `0`:

```
def binLimit1s( bits, ones, prefix=[] ):
    if bits<ones:
        yield prefix
    elif ones==0:
        yield prefix + [0]*bits
    elif ones==bits:
        yield prefix + [1]*bits
    else:
        for x in binLimit1s( bits-1, ones, prefix+[0] ):
            yield x
        for x in binLimit1s( bits-1, ones-1, prefix+[1] ):
            yield x
```

In your case, you would use

```
binLimit1s( 32, 12 )
```

Comment: I was just about to post almost the same algorithm :D

Comment: You could provide the output for `binLimit1s(5, 3)` to illustrate how the results look like.

Comment: @swenzel: Creepy: that's exactly the example I used for testing...